# C compilation problem

Tags: c, cygwin

I am learning how to use cygwin for alchemy. I created a test library celconv.h which is there inside the folder celconv. I want to use that header file in my c code.

When i use `#include <celconv/celconv.h>` the compiler gives an error `"No such file or directory"`

i compile the code like this:

```
gcc -c test.c
```

`Test.c` inside a folder named test

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <celconv/celconv.h>

int main()
{
    float UserInput;

    printf("Enter a temperature in celsius to convert to  fahrenheit:");
    scanf("%f",&UserInput);
    celconvert(UserInput);

    return 0;
}
```

`celconv.h` inside a folder celconv which is inside test folder:

```
extern void celconv(float Cel);
```

`celconv.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"celconv.h"

void celconvert(float Cel)
{

    float Fah;

    Fah = Cel * 9/5 + 32;
    printf("%f",Fah);
}
```

Comment: Please post any relevant code.

Comment: and the full path to *celconv*. The implementation of the functions on celconv.h should be done in celconv.c.

Comment: And you never talked about a test.c file (which might be missing)

Comment: Hint: how does the compiler know where to find celconv.h? What if you placed celconv.h in "gofindme" folder?

Comment: As a sidenote, this code is incorrect: Cel * 9/5 + 32; It depends on the order of evaluation. It needs to be changed to Cel * 9.0f/5.0f + 32.0f;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the path you are giving correct? Be careful about using  `< >`  and  `" "`. The first tells the compiler "search for include files in your include folder", while the second says "look into source files directory".

Answer (score 2):

If the "celconv" directory is in the current directory, the best way is probably use `#include "celconv/celconv.h"` syntax. If it is somewhere else, then do this:

```
gcc -I/path/to/wherever/celconv/directory/is -c test.c
```

Note that it's *not* the path to the celconv directory itself, but to the containing directory!

As mentioned in the comment, this approach will work for the current directory too if you don't want to use "celconv/celconv.h" for whatever reason:

```
gcc -I. -c test.c
```

Comment: This time i tried by pasting the celconv folder adjacent to "test" folder and i gave the location as gcc -I/celconv/ test.c It gave me the same error

Comment: @karthick, what do you mean, "adjacent"? Like, you have /some/path/test with test.c in it and /some/path/celconv? Then, if you run GCC from /some/path/test, you should run it as `gcc -I.. -c test.c` or `gcc -I/some/path -c test.c`. The point is that you should give GCC the path to the directory where the "celconv" directory is located. But what you wrote in your comment looks like you have "celconv" in the root of the file hierarchy, which is doubtful.

Comment: @above Sorry for my wrong typing. The celconv directory is under D:\cworkspace\celconv\celconv.h where as my test.c file is in D:\alchemy\alchemy-5.0a\samples\test\test.c. I am giving the path as gcc -I/D:/cworkspace/celconv/ -test.c

Comment: As I've said, you should give the path to the directory where the "celconv" directory is located. In your case, it's `-I/D:/cworkspace`.

Comment: Added a clarifying note to the answer. It was unclear, I admit.

Answer (score 1):

Include files in the local directory need to be referenced using the
    #include "file.h"
syntax. The angle brackets do not look into the current directory.